# Count number of specific file type of a directory and its sub dir in mac

Tags: macos, unix, terminal

I use `ls -l *.filetype | wc -l` but it can only find files in current directory.
How can I also count all files with specific extension in its sub dirs?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 94, accepted):

You can do that with `find` command:

```
find . -name "*.filetype" | wc -l
```

Answer (score 2):

The following compound command, albeit somewhat verbose, guarantees an accurate count because it [handles filenames that contain newlines](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/020) correctly:

```
total=0; while read -rd ''; do ((total++)); done < <(find . -name "*.filetype" -print0) && echo "$total"
```

**Note:** Before running the aforementioned compound command:

1. Firstly, [`cd`](https://ss64.com/osx/cd.html) to the directory that you want to count all files with specific extension in.
2. Change the `filetype` part as appropriate, e.g. `txt`

---

**Demo:**

To further demonstrate why piping the results of [`find`](https://ss64.com/osx/find.html) to [`wc -l`](https://ss64.com/osx/wc.html) may produce  incorrect results:

1. Run the following compound command to quickly create some test files:

   ```
   mkdir -p ~/Desktop/test/{1..2} && touch ~/Desktop/test/{1..2}/a-file.txt && touch ~/Desktop/test/{1..2}/$'b\n-file.txt'
   ```

   This produces the following directory structure on your *"Desktop"*:

   ```
   test
   ├── 1
   │   ├── a-file.txt
   │   └── b\n-file.txt
   └── 2
       ├── a-file.txt
       └── b\n-file.txt
   ```

   <sub>**Note:** It contains a total of four `.txt` files. Two of which have multi-line filenames, i.e. `b\n-file.txt`</sub>.

   <sub>On newer version of macOS the files named `b\n-file.txt` will appear as `b?-file.txt` in the *"Finder"*, i.e. A question mark indicates the newline in a multi-line filename</sub>
2. Then run the following command that pipes the results of `find` to `wc -l`:

   ```
   find ~/Desktop/test -name "*.txt" | wc -l
   ```

   It ***incorrectly*** reports/prints:

   > `6`
3. Then run the following suggested compound command:

   ```
   total=0; while read -rd ''; do ((total++)); done < <(find ~/Desktop/test -name "*.txt" -print0) && echo "$total"
   ```

   It ***correctly*** reports/prints:

   > `4`